# tooltip dynamically update content not working under firefox

Tags: javascript, html, tooltip

I have a very strange issue about tooltip. The following code works under Chrome but not in Firefox, in firefox, tooltip content is never reseted with the following code:

```
$('.tooltip-tag').tooltip("option", "content", dynamicContent)
```

dynamicContent is always changing across time.

I also tried **$('.tooltip-tag').tooltip({content: dynamicContent})**, this is not working also. I am trying to think out a way to turn the tooltip off and then turn it on so that I can set the content every time when I need to update the content, but it doesn't look like a right way to do it.

Any suggestion or hint would be helpful.

Many thanks!

Comment: I have not seen a jQuery member function take more than a 2-tuple while using a comma delimiter.

Comment: @AlexW, well now you have ... It is perfectly well documented -> http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#method-option

Comment: `$(selector).tooltip("option", "content", "something")` works for me in both chrome and FF -> **http://jsfiddle.net/zp0Lkdyq/**

Answer (score 0):

Can you dynamically update the `title` attribute?

```
$('.tooltip-tag').attr('title',dynamicContent);
```

and then possibly do another `$('.tooltip-tag').tooltip()` call to force an update?